# How to add two pointers on the same Jslider?

Tags: java, jslider

As of now, I have two different Jsliders in the same panel/frame. One ask for X value. and other for Y. I realize if I can have ONE slider for both the values but two pointers on same slider, it would be more interactive for the user.  To distinguish the pointers from each other, it would be nice to color code the pointer just for X and different color for the Y pointer.

Any suggestions on adding one more pointer?

Answer (score 1):

> To distinguish the pointers from each
>   other, it would be nice to color code
>   the pointer just for X and different
>   color for the Y pointer

And what happens when the user wants to choose the same X/Y value and the pointers are painted on top of one another? What if you want to readjust the bottom pointer, are you going to have to move the top pointer first before moving the bottom pointer?

I suggest you stick with the simple approach and use two sliders. This is a UI users are familiar with.

Comment: (for a vertical slider) 
top pointer will be for X, and bottom for Y.